# xcopy one file to many computers in txt file

Tags: powershell, cmd, psexec, xcopy

I am trying to copy one script file (DBFF.cmd) to many computers. I have created a computerlist.txt to list the names of each computer. On each line I have just the list of names ex. (win-ali) will someone please tell me where I may be going wrong?

```
for /F %%a in (computerlist.txt) do xcopy "\\tc\Install\Firefox_Deploy\DBFF.cmd" "\\%%a\c$\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp"
```

Comment: Are you running this from a command prompt or from within a batch file? What error do you get?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what issues/errors you're encountering, it's going to be difficult to troubleshoot.

That being said, your example should work within a batch file. It will not work straight from the command line.

If you need it to work from the command line, change `%%a` to `%a`:

```
for /F %a in (computerlist.txt) do xcopy "\\tc\Install\Firefox_Deploy\DBFF.cmd" "\\%a\c$\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp"
```

Here's an old Microsoft post about the percent signs being stripped from batch files: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/75634